# Passing variables to function context

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was a way to do something along the lines of :

```
function testFunction(a, b) {
   console.log(a + b, c);
}
testFunction(2,3); // Should print "5, undefined"
testFunction.localContext.c = "foo";
testFunction(2,3); // Should print "5, foo"
```

In fact, I'd like to be able to set the variables of the context of a function.

Thanks !

Details, in fact, I have this :

```
   function requestHandler(req, res) {
       function validateMsg(str) {
            // Do stuff with req.user and str and so on
       }
       var msg = req.body.message;
       if (validateMsg(msg)) {
           send(msg);
       }
   }
```

My problem is that I'd like to move the function "validateMsg" to the top, so I can use it in other requests handlers. But if I do so, I lose its localScope. That's why I'd like to change it.

Comment: I don't think you can do this, except for the special `this` variable, which you can set using `.bind()`.

Comment: @Barmar you can, JavaScripts functions are themselves objects. See my answer.

Comment: @jrsala Your answer solves it in a different way. It doesn't actually set a local variable in the function's scope.

Comment: The same thing could be done using a global variable.

Comment: But `this` doesn't solve the problem either. A freestanding identifier `c` will not refer to `this.c`, no matter the value of `this`...

Comment: @Barmar I think the purpose of `localContext` may have been to avoid the use of a *global*

Comment: It is not possible to refer to a function environment in any way. You could use `with` (e.g. `with({c: 'foo'}) { testFunction(2,3); }`) to avoid polluting the outer environment with `c`,  but `with` is deprecated and it wouldn't only affect the function environment either.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this anyway? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't pass whatever  `validateMsg` needs as parameters to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that I'd like to move the function "validateMsg" to the top, so I can use it in other requests handlers. But if I do so, I lose its localScope. That's why I'd like to change it.

Well, JavaScript has lexical scope, not dynamic scope. There is no way for you to change the function's environment.

I don't see why you can't pass `req` or `req.user` as argument to the function. If the function can only work if it has access to a request object or the user, it should be part of the functions parameters:

```
function validateMsg(str, user) {
     // Do stuff with user and str and so on
}

function requestHandler(req, res) {
   var msg = req.body.message;
   if (validateMsg(msg, req.user)) {
       send(msg);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's just what I wanted to know, if there was a way to dynamically change the scope of a function. But if it's lexical, then there is no way to do so.

Thanks !

Comment: See my post below for an **calling object** solution as a way to access caller context.

Comment: @MaxZoom: Sure you can use `this`, but there is not really a benefit in doing so. In fact, it makes the API of the function less clear.

Comment: I agree that the function API will be less clear than passing a parameter. But it was meant as  possible solution to set variables of function context through the calling object

Answer (score 1):

No, but objects are meant to solve that problem. If a bit of functionality needs to take data along with it, objects are the way to go, and it turns out JavaScript functions are themselves objects!

```
function testFunction(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b, testFunction.c);
}

testFunction(2,3); // Prints "5, undefined"
testFunction.c = "foo";
testFunction(2,3); // Prints "5, foo"
```

**edit:** Making this independent from the name of the function:

```
function setCAndCall(f, c) {
    f.c = c;
    f(2,3);
}

setCAndCall(testFunction, "foo"); // prints "5, foo"
// and you can do that with any function, not just testFunction
```

However the definition of `f` will have to refer to itself, just in the same way that `testFunction` refers to `testFunction.c` in its body. Your best bet at this point if you want everything to be independent from the function nae is to use a proper object and the `this` keyword, as pointed out in other answers.

Comment: This would be perfect if there was a keyword such as "function.c" instead of "testFunction.c", because I'd like something independent of the function name

Comment: @JeanGabriel It really sounds like you have a problem you should not have. But if you want the setting of the c variable to be independent from the name of the function, that's easy too, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear, sorry. I meant, in the body of the function, I don't like using its name. It sounds redoundant.
I added details about my problem in main message too. Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Dear downvoters, the question was edited and expanded after my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A another approach would be to define an object that encapsulates the third element:

```js
var test = {
  c: undefined,
  fn: function(a, b) {
    console.log(a+b, this.c);
  }
}

test.fn(2,3); // prints '5, undefined'
test.c = 99;
test.fn(2,3); // prints '5, 99'
```

Comment: I don't like the fact that it had to make a whole new object encapsulating it in order for it to work.

I will put more details about the problem, as I was not clear

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is not exactly what you asked for but do you think you can make something out of it. `arguments` is the array variable that is there inside a function context which will hold all the arguments that are passed, You dont even have to declare variables.

```
function testFunction() {
  var c = [];
  for(var i in arguments){
    c.push(arguments[i]); // you can do anything with the number of variables or iterations
  }
  console.log(c.join(','));
}
testFunction(2,3); // Should print "2,3"
testFunction(2,3,'foo'); // Should print "2,3, foo"
testFunction('1', 2, 3,'foo', 88); // Should print "1, 2, 3, foo, 88"
```

#### EDIT 2: Problem Statement

move fn `validateMsg()` out of fn `requestHandler()` scope

```
function validateMsg() {
    var str = arguments[0];
    var req = arguments[1];
    var res = arguments[2];
    // Do stuff with req.user and str and so on
}
function requestHandler(req, res) {
   var msg = req.body.message;
   if (validateMsg(msg,req,res)) {
       send(msg);
   }
}
```

I guess you can just pass the arguments as you like also you can choose not to so do not forget to add a **null check** to `req` and `res` ie `arguments[1]` and `arguments[2]`

Comment: @Jean Gabriel What was the problem that you were trying to solve?

Comment: I added details. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Jean Gabriel : Please check my post **Edit 2**. Hope this helps. I guess this is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: I don't even know why you did "arguments[0]", you could just make validateMsg(str, req, res) :D. My problem is that I don't want to change the inside of the function in order for it to work. That's why this solution doesn't satisfy me ^^

Comment: @JeanGabriel You are not getting the point you can also do `validateMsg(msg,this)` and then `arguments[1]` will have the local scope of any `requestHandler()` you can use it as you choose to

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to reuse the `validateMsg(..)` function for different request handlers, then you can call this method with the handler context itself, accessing it though the `this` keyword:

```js
function validateMsg(str) {
  return str == this.req.user;
}

function requestHandler1(req, res) {
  var msg = req.message;
  if (validateMsg.call(this, msg)) {
    alert(msg);
  }
}

function requestHandler2(req, res) {
  var msg = "dude";
  if (validateMsg.call(this, msg)) {
    alert(msg);
  }
}

var req = { message: "abc", user: "abc" }
var res = {}
requestHandler1(req, res);
requestHandler2(req, res);
```

See official [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for details on `Function.prototype.call(..)`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is the solution to your problem, but you asked about setting a variable in the context of a function.

To set a variable in the scope of the function, you cannot assign it to an externally visible property - that's not the same thing.  You need to either create a closure (by creating a function that returns `testFunction`) or else do something like the following, but note that the order of the arguments matters so you can't do exactly what you're asking for but something very close:

```
var testFunction = function(a,b,c){
  console.log(a+b, c);
 };

testFunction(2,3) // "5, undefined"

testFunction = testFunctio.bind(testFunction, 1);// now a=1 in testFunction    
testFunction(2,3); // "3, 3" , because a=1, and b,c=2,3      

// or if you don't want to alter testFunction
testFunction.bind(testFunction, 1)(2,3);
```